# error: incompatible types: <anonymous Observer<AverageBudget>> cannot be converted to Observer<? super List<AverageBudget>>

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm using an observer, while trying to fix my code I had an error message on the observer and I pressed Alt+enter to quick fix it now it is crossed out like so:
[image]

In all honesty I dont know how I have done this nor do I know how to restore it. If there are any ways to revert what I have done please tell me.

Comment: In Android Studio with the default settings this usually means that the class is deprecated, however `Observer` has been available from API 1.  Check that your import is still `java.util.Observer` and not something different.

Answer (score 1):

The crossed out line on `Observer` does mean it is deprecated.
You can check the same in your import list and you'd find an import containing observer in it. And being said that its deprecated you shouldn't implement `Observer` and `Observable` anymore.

How and why this got deprecated could be found [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8154801).

They didn't provide a rich enough event model for applications. For example, they could support only the notion that something has changed, but didn't convey any information about what has changed.

Perhaps, instead of using Observer you can use Listener pattern as they both are similar.
But Observer has a weakness: all observables are the same. You have to implement the logic that is based on `instanceof` and cast object to concrete type into `Observable.update()` method.

Listeners are different. There are a lot of listener types. For example mouse listener, keyboard listener etc. Each one has several callback methods (i.e. `keyPressed()`, `keyReleased()` etc). So, you never have to implement the logic that should answer the question "is it my event" into the event handler.

I think that this is why listener model is preferable.

To add to it there were bugs like one [could not serialize the](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4180466) `Observable` class because as it didn't implement `Serializable` interface and all of its members were private.

**What is a better alternative to that?**

On the other hand `Listeners have a lot of types and they have callback methods and don't require casting. As pointed by @Ravi in his answer you can make use of [PropertyChangeListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html) instead.

For the rest of it the `@Deprecation` has been marked with proper documentation to explore other packages as linked in other answers as well.

Hope that helps.